# Есть ли алгоритм конвертации десятичного числа в двоичное?

Tags: javascript, системы-счисления

Есть ли метод для перевода например числа 42 в двоичное?

Comment: Этот алгоритм называется разложение числа по основанию 2

Comment: `(42).toString(2)`

Comment: Битовый сдвиг и AND, больше ничего не нужно для вывода двоичного числа. На Си это будет выглядеть так: `for (int offset = 63; offset >= 0; --offset) cout << ((number >> offset) & 1) << endl;`.

Comment: `42 = 1 *2⁵ + 0 *2⁴ + 1 *2³ + 0 *2² + 1 *2¹ + 0 *2⁰` → `101010`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const num = 42;
const binNum = num.toString(2); // перевод в двоичную
const binNumParse = parseInt(binNum, 2); // обратно

console.log(binNum);
console.log(binNumParse);
```